# Why the loop is infinite?

Tags: python

When I use this code, it runs infinite loop, and the image which I want to show it ,does not respond and appear as a gray picture

```
    h,w=Img.size
    for x in range(h):
        for y in range (w):
            r, g, b = Img.getpixel((x, y))
            a = (r, g, b)
            print (a)
    cv2.imshow("Mark Zukerberg", Img)
```

Comment: It's not infinite, but it's going to take long especially if you write to the console that much.

Comment: Why unpack the pixel into r, g, b just to cram them back into a tuple immediately?

Comment: please try with a smaller image with much lesser size. Also do not print as much.

Comment: Your whole nested loop is just for printing out every pixel. You should drop that at all. And BTW `img` and `Img` are not the same.

Comment: Running this code on a 1920x1080 pixel image would result in over 2 million print statements. OP, what are you trying to do here? What is your end goal?

Comment: Besides the nested loops, a `getpixel` operation is by itself very slow.  If you need to process a large image, the image libraries all have functions to convert the image to a numpy array, where you can access the pixels through normal array indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop isn't actually infinite, it is just a very long, large, process, so it will take a while to finish. If you were to have it print y and/or x every time it iterates, you can see it is incrementing, just more slowly then wanted. I would recommend using a compiled language, such as C++, Java, or Go for loops this large, as they will run faster.

Comment: Suggesting another language is only slightly more helpful an answer than one written in gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

print actually takes more resources than you would expect, so that might be the issue. Try removing the print function.